# Javascript await a function inside an async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I have the following codes:

```
    function test1() {
        test2.execute();
    }
```

I am trying to use await inside an async function to make test1() execute first:

```
    it("title", async () => {
        await test1();
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(true);
    })
```

But somehow the function `test1()` does not execute before `firebase.assertSucceeds(true)`. `test1()` returns a callback. I tried to use the callback, and it does not help either.

```
    function test1() {
        test2.execute().then(() => {
            return;
        });
    }

    it("title", async () => {
        let x = await test1();
        await firebase.assertSucceeds(true);
    })
```

Still synchronous. what did I do wrong here?

Comment: I think test1 also needs to be async, for await to actually wait for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first snippet you are awaiting for test1 which returns void (nothing), for the await to work it should be applyed to a promise, you acheive that either by returning test2.execute() which returns a Promise :

```
function test1() {
    return test2.execute();
}
```

or by making test1 async and await for test2 to finish executing :

```
async function test1() {
    await test2.execute();
}
```

ps: an async function returns a resolved promise with the return as the resolution value so for example :

```
async function test(){
    return 2;
}
```

is translated under the hood to this:

```
function test(){
    return Promise.resolve(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function has to return a `Promise` if you want to `await` it.

For example:

```js
function test1() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("I'm done")
    }, 500)
  })
}
```

Notice, in the [firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/unit-tests), that `assertSucceeds` only takes a promise as it's one and only argument. So consider passing it a [promise that always resolves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) if that's what you're going for to begin with.

```js
await firebase.assertSucceeds(Promise.resolve())
```